# exporting from Access to CSV without decimals but they keep showing

Tags: csv, ms-access, ms-access-2010

am exporting a query table to a CSV file and its all working ok but my only problem is that the Salary Field is showing two decimals after the export that i dont want,what i tried so far is 
1- reformat the field in the query to loose the decimals like this

```
Amount: Format(Salary,"0")
```

when i run the query (inside Access) there are no decimals but after the export they are still there
2- remove the decimals from (Region and Language) in the control panel(i dont like this approach) and the result is that the Zeros are gone but the decimal point still there.

Comment: Can you post an example of the output file as it will appear opened in Notepad?

Comment: @Gustav Never mind ,i re-installed Office and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a faulty Office app,re installing it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert to `long`

```
Amount: CLng(Salary)
```

Comment: the problem persist,nothing changed

Comment: Are you opening the CSV with excel? if yes, open with a text editor, like notepad and check it

Comment: Never mind ,i re-installed Office and the problem disappeared,thanks!.